# Function "sort" and compare are a huge mistake help me with this

Tags: haskell

Probrally i'm doing huge mistakes about this, this is my fisrt attempt to coding in haskell so How do I implements the sort function in 2 lists to get the two highest valeus in which list

```
ssort:: [Double] -> [Double] -> t
ssort xs ys = compareList (sort xs) (sort ys)

compareList:: [Double] -> [Double] -> Boolean
compareList [] [] x _ = do
compareList xs ys |
    (head xs > head ys)  
  | (head xs < head ys)
  | (head xs == head ys) = compareList (tail xs) (tail ys)
```

Comment: What does that mean? "implements the sort function in 2 lists to get the two highest valeus in which list" -- are you trying to find the highest value in each list, or the two highest values of the two lists combined, or are you trying to sort them both into a big list, or what? Try and clarify your question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Lets go Line by Line

ssort:: [Double] -> [Double] -> t

`ssort` is a function that takes a list of doubles (`[Double]`) and another List of doubles (`[Double]`) and returns something (t).  I believe you want a List of Doubles back. So it should be:

```
ssort:: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
                                --------
```

Now how do we write such a function?  You have:

```
ssort xs ys = compareList (sort xs) (sort ys)
```

Which works only if `compareList :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]`

Now to write `compareList`.  You have:

```
compareList [] [] x _ = do
```

I think you want to write the base case where both of the lists are empty, but you have too many parameters.  I'm not sure what you intend with the `do` block, but this is a pure function so leave those out for the moment.

```
compareList [] [] = [] -- if both lists are empty the result is empty
-- Note you need to add something here.  See below
```

Now you want to write a function that compares the first element of each list and puts the largest at the front. It looks like you want to use [guard syntax](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/functional-programming-haskell/0/steps/27226). So I will do that as well, but I prefer to use `case` myself. Remember each guard needs a expression (something to the right of the `=` sign)

```
compareList xs ys
  | (head xs >= head ys) = ((head xs):compareList(tail xs, ys))
    -- note I have made the first list dominant when the first elements are equal
  | otherwise = ((head ys):compareList(xs, tail ys))
    -- (head xs < head ys) must hold no need to check
```

If you don't understand why I wrote `((head xs):compareList(tail xs, ys))`, you need to read about [recursive functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) and [list construction](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/functional-programming-haskell/0/steps/27211).

Now we are missing something.  What happens when one list is empty but the other list is not?  Easy, we just return the rest of the list, and this is important, we *must* do that before we try to use `head` or `tail` as both fail on an empty list.  So back where I left that comment we need:

```
compareList [] ys = ys
compareList xs [] = xs
```

If you take a moment and really look at this you will realize that these two cases will also handle the situation where both lists are empty.

Ok, here is everything in order

```
ssort:: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
ssort xs ys = compareList (sort xs) (sort ys)

compareList :: [Double] -> [Double] -> [Double]
compareList [] ys = ys
compareList xs [] = xs
compareList xs ys
  | (head xs >= head ys) = ((head xs):compareList(tail xs, ys))
    -- note I have made the first list dominant when the first elements are equal
  | otherwise = ((head ys):compareList(xs, tail ys))
    -- (head xs < head ys) must hold no need to check
```

Some asides

- It is completely possible to write `ssort xs ys = sort(xs ++ ys)` but that doesn't teach you anything.
- It is generally good practice in Haskell to write polymorphic functions. We would prefer to write `ssort:: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which can be read for any type `a` which can be ordered, given two lists of `a` this function returns a list of the same type. If this makes no sense to you just tuck it away until you hit [type classes](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) and come back later.

Comment: A brave attempt for a confusing question.